Having trouble with 'accessDenied' in Microsoft Graph for recent files in a SharePoint site
Using the Microsoft Graph Explorer with the following OAuth scopes:
offline_access
openid
profile
email
Mail.Send
User.Read
Files.ReadWrite.All
Sites.ReadWrite.All

-- so look to have permissions covered.
If I do a GET on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/:siteId/drive
The following is returned:
{
  '@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives/$entity',
  createdDateTime: '2023-05-20T23:20:12Z',
  description: '',
  id: 'b!ZVW3mC07Ck2fnj47xT3h02LQsvIyQjrqceQpFvTR0S1e1IUAqav15AMInFCkSIsA',
  lastModifiedDateTime: '2024-05-16T16:11:31Z',
  name: 'Documents',
  webUrl: 'https://xample.sharepoint.com/sites/SomedaySite/Shared%20Documents',
  driveType: 'documentLibrary',
  createdBy: { user: { displayName: 'System Account' } },
  lastModifiedBy: {
    user: {
      email: 'e5admin@xample.onmicrosoft.com',
      id: '596a9690-ab24-4dbc-b8ef-5e626fa001e2',
      displayName: 'Jane Doe'
    }
  },
  owner: {
    group: {
      email: 'SomedaySite@xample.onmicrosoft.com',
      id: '8e46abd5-fd42-4b0b-b6ef-59cb232053fe',
      displayName: 'Someday Site Owners'
    }
  },
  quota: {
    deleted: 0,
    remaining: 27487788554469,
    state: 'normal',
    total: 27487790694400,
    used: 2139931
  }
}

If I do a GET on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/x:siteId/drive/root 
The following is returned:
{
  '@odata.context': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(driveItem)/$entity',
  '@microsoft.graph.Decorator': 'decorator has been deprecated. Refer to folder.decorator',
  createdDateTime: '2023-05-20T23:20:12Z',
  id: '01WGOKW5F6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ',
  lastModifiedDateTime: '2024-05-20T20:27:41Z',
  name: 'root',
  parentReference: {
    driveType: 'documentLibrary',
    driveId: 'b!ZVW3mC07Ck2fnj47xT3UAqav15AMInFCkSIsAh02LQsvIyQjrqceQpFvTR0S1e1I'
  },
  webUrl: 'https://xample.sharepoint.com/sites/SomedaySite/Shared%20Documents',
  fileSystemInfo: {
    createdDateTime: '2023-05-20T23:20:12Z',
    lastModifiedDateTime: '2024-05-20T20:27:41Z'
  },
  folder: { childCount: 3 },
  root: {},
  size: 81011
}


But if I do a GET on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/:siteId/drive/recent
The following error is returned:
{
  error: {
    code: 'accessDenied',
    message: 'The current caller is not the drive owner.',
    innerError: {
      date: '2024-05-27T17:00:53',
      'request-id': '09988d39-2ecc-46d0-ba52-dd0187070c8e',
      'client-request-id': '09988d39-2ecc-46d0-ba52-dd0187070c8e'
    }
  }
}

I appear to have sufficient permissions according to this.
 Why would the first 2 calls work, but the 3rd call fail?
 How can I get a list of recent files and (especially) folders from my SharePoint site?

Hi, Looks like you are not the owner of the site. According to Microsoft Documentation the recent endpoint will give response to site's owner recent files only.

@ShivaKeshavVarma Yes, you're completely correct. Not the site owner, so it looks like the recent files endpoint is not supported. Thats so completely weird, but hey.
